# Trying to add a user to multiple groups in AD. This does not add all of them for some reason. Only some

Tags: vbscript, scripting, active-directory

This is my code. And while it sort of works, it for some reason does not add every group in the list I have pasted in. I think my ordering of statements is totally off and causing this. But I just can't get every single entry in the array to add to a user.

```
On Error Resume Next
'AD Path to the user container
strinput = "testuser"
memberPath = "LDAP://CN=" & strinput & ",OU=Users - Employee,OU=ALL USERS,DC=mydomain,DC=mycompany,DC=org"

'paths for relevant OUs in AD
strSecgrppath = ",OU=Security Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=mycompany,DC=org"
strDisgrppath = ",OU=Distribution Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=mycompany,DC=org"
strMEsecpath = ",OU=Microsoft Exchange Security Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=mycompany,DC=org"
strPrntrgrppath = ",OU=Printer Groups,OU=Security Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=mycompany,DC=org"

'Input for entry of array variables. This where we copy paste the Groups
strGroups = inputbox("Enter exact Group names separated by commas.", "Enter exact Group names separated by commas.")
'splits the array and iterates through it, calling the subroutine with  
'each specific AD path variable

'I paste in the groups like: "Employees, Admins, Volunteers, Serviceaccounts, etc.
strSEC = Split(strGroups, ", ")
limit = UBound(strSEC)
' Go through the Sec Groups OU
For i=0 To limit
  Call iterategroups (strSecgrppath)
Next
'No need to explain, goes through the next group.
For i=0 To limit
  Call iterategroups (strDisgrppath)
Next
'etc.
For i=0 To limit
  Call iterategroups (strMEsecpath)
Next
'etc.
For i=0 To limit
  Call iterategroups (strPrntrgrppath)
Next

'the sub for going through each OU
Sub iterategroups(groupparam)
  ' ADsPath to the Security group container
  groupPath = "LDAP://mydomain.mycompany.org/CN=" & strSEC(i) & groupparam

  ' Set the Group object
  Set group = GetObject(groupPath)

  ' Set the Member object
  Set member = GetObject(memberPath)

  ' adds the member to the group
  group.Add(member.ADsPath)
End Sub
```

Comment: First step in VBScript debugging: remove global `On Error Resume Next` and actually see what breaks.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a much easier way to do this by cloning the memberof attribute for an existing user in AD, which was the purpose of this script to begin with.

```
'Create the AD object
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
strinput = "testuser"
'Enter the display name of the user whose permissions need to be cloned. 
strUserDN = inputbox("Enter Display Name of User to be cloned.")

'LDAP Path for the new user
memberPath = "LDAP://CN=" & strinput & ",OU=Users - Employee,OU=ALL USERS,DC=mydomain,DC=mycompany,DC=org"

'LDAP Path for the user to be cloned.
oldmemberPath = "LDAP://CN=" & strUserDN & ",OU=Users - Employee,OU=ALL USERS,DC=mydomain,DC=mycompany,DC=org"

'resume next to avoid error if new user belongs to the same group already.
on error resume next

'sets the object for the user to be cloned
Set objUser = GetObject(oldmemberPath)

'Pulls a list of items from the memberof attribute of the user to be cloned and adds it to an array
arrGroups = objUser.memberOf

'For each group in the array, add Groups for new user
For Each strGroup In arrGroups
  ' Set the Group object
  Set group = GetObject("LDAP://mydomain.mycompany.org/" & strGroup)

  ' Set the Member object
  Set member = GetObject(memberPath)

  ' adds the new user to the group
  group.Add(member.ADsPath)
Next
```